# Why does this node-mysql insert yield an array?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise, q

According to the node-mysql [documentation](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql), the result of inserting a row into a table with an auto_increment primary key is an object, one of whose fields is insertId. However, I do not see this in running the code below. Instead, I see that the result is a two element array, whose first element is an object of the desired type, but whose second element is `undefined`. In particular, the code below prints:

```
[ { fieldCount: 0,
    affectedRows: 1,
    insertId: 12,
    serverStatus: 2,
    warningCount: 0,
    message: '',
    protocol41: true,
    changedRows: 0 },
  undefined ]
```

Can anyone explain this discrepancy between the docs and the observed behavior?

Code:

```
var mysql = require("mysql")
var Q = require("q")


var db = {
        "host": "localhost",
        "user": "root",
        "password": "xyz",
        "database": "study"
}

var pool  = mysql.createPool(db);
var getConnection = Q.nbind(pool.getConnection, pool)

getConnection().then(function (connection) {
    Q.ninvoke(connection, 'query', "insert into tsheet (cname) values('reformation');")
        .then(
            function (rslt) {
                console.log(rslt)
                process.exit(0)
            })
}).done()
```

Here is the table:

```
mysql> describe tsheet;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| cid   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| cname | varchar(256) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`node-mysql` [expects a callback](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#introduction) with *three* parameters: `err, rows, fields`.  `Q` is taking the latter two of those parameters and putting them into an array so the next function is called with only one parameter.  (`err` is handled separately in `.catch`).  Since this is an INSERT, the fields parameter is undefined.

If you want to take both of those parameters separately, use [`.spread`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#combination):

```
Q.ninvoke(connection, 'query', "insert into tsheet (cname) values('reformation');")
  .spread(
    function (rslt, fields) {
      console.log(rslt)
      process.exit(0)
    });
```

Comment: Good answer, I'd like to add `.get` is also useful here.

Comment: I expect this is a good answer if you already bring some knowledge (of node-mysql) to the table. For me, sorry but the answer is impenetrable. Using `.spread` is standard fare, but the reduction of three params to two is somewhat arcane.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 How's that?

Comment: SomeKittens, your latest edit helps but "so there's only one callback" is still confusing me.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 My mistake.  Brain fart.

Comment: SomeKittens, got it! Thank you, now I agree with Ben G - good answer.